# Is it possible to invert order of destruction?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, constructor, destructor

I have a base class that implements many basic functionalities and it needs some "storage" (memory block) that must be provided by a class that inherits it (or the user).

```
class Base
{
public:

    Base(void* storage, size_t storageSize) :
        storage_{storage},
        storageSize_{storageSize}
    {
        // do something with the storage...
    }

    ~Base()
    {
        // do something with the storage...
    }

    // member functions

private:

    void* storage_;
    size_t storageSize_;
};
```

The important note here is that this memory block **is** used in constructor and destructor.

This works very well when the child class uses static storage:

```
template<size_t Size>
class StaticObject : public Base
{
public:

    StaticObject() :
        Base{&storage, Size}
    {

    }

private:

    typename std::aligned_storage<Size>::type staticStorage_;
};
```

I know that the storage is used before it is constructed (it is "constructed" after the constructor of Base finishes) and after it is destructed (it is "destructed" before the destructor of Base starts running), but for the trivial `std::aligned_storage<...>::type` this makes no difference.

However this idea fails completely when I want to use it with dynamically allocated storage:

```
class DynamicObject : public Base
{
public:

    DynamicObject(size_t size) :
        DynamicObject{std::unique_ptr<uint8_t>{new uint8_t[size]}, size}
    {

    }

private:

    DynamicObject(std::unique_ptr<uint8_t>&& dynamicStorage, size_t size) :
        Base{dynamicStorage.get(), size},
        dynamicStorage_{std::move(dynamicStorage)}
    {

    }

    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t> dynamicStorage_;
};
```

As you see with the delegating constructor I managed to create (allocate) the storage before it will be used in the constructor of `Base` - "inverting" the order of construction a little bit. This particular phase also works fine. The problem is the destructor, as I really cannot think of any solution to my problem - in the code above, the dynamically allocated storage would be deallocated before the destructor of `Base` starts running (and using this memory block)...

For now I had to solve this differently - instead of inheriting from `Base`, the `DynamicObject` class contains the `unique_ptr` and the object of `Base` as member variables - this way I control the order of construction/destruction, but there are also some negative sides:

- I have to provide a wrapper for every function from `Base` that should be exposed by the derived classes
- I have to provide conversion operators to (const) reference to `Base`, as I would like to use the objects via reference to the base class

I have thought about using multiple inheritance, so that `DynamicObject` would inherit from two bases - one that would provide storage (private inheritance) and from `Base` (to inherit the functionality) - this way I would also get the right order of construction/destruction, but at the price of using the "evil" multiple inheritance...

Please note that the example above is just a simplification. The real use cases are objects like threads and message queues for the RTOS that I'm writing ( https://github.com/DISTORTEC/distortos ) - see the `Dynamic*.hpp` and `Static*.hpp` objects for real examples - https://github.com/DISTORTEC/distortos/tree/master/include/distortos

Is there any clever trick that I could use to somehow invert the order of destruction? Something like the use of delegating constructor of `DynamicObject` above? Maybe there is a better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Split Base into two classes, a class that stores the memory (and is polymorphic) and a class that uses the memory. Make the latter hold an instance of the former, passed as a constructor parameter.

Comment: I worry that *any* design along these lines would be fragile, and that you'd be better off thinking more about the overall design than how to make the details of this particular implementation approach work.

Comment: Define an interface for allocation/deallocation, manage the memory in the base, and provide the implementations from the derived classes.

Comment: @NeilKirk - could you provide an example in an answer? If I understand you correctly I would have to hold the instance of the polymorphic object using dynamic memory, which would defeat the whole purpose of having class like StaticObject...

Comment: @Hurkyl - I'm completely open to any suggestions here. I just didn't come up with anything better than the {Static,Dynamic}Object idea presented above - I'd like to have both types without duplicating the functionality implemented in base class - it's just the "source" of memory block (stack / heap) that is different in these types.

Comment: @AlanStokes - it won't work, as virtual functions in constructor/destructor don't work as in "normal" functions.

Comment: @FreddieChopin True but irrelevant if the memory manager is a separate object, which is what I was suggesting.

Comment: @AlanStokes - the final outcome of this solution would be very similar to the one I implemented - to make this usable I would need a "holder" class (with the base and manager as members) + conversion operators + wrappers for all member functions.

Comment: The title of this question is an XY problem. The problem isn't inverting the order of destruction. The problem is ultimately caused by using a raw pointer in your base class. In a C++11 environment, it would be better to use either a `std::unique_ptr` or a `std::shared_ptr` instead of that raw pointer. Which to use depends on how that memory is to be used elsewhere, and you haven't discussed that.

Comment: @DavidHammen - now (after comment by @BenVoigt) I know that I could use unique_ptr with both dynamic memory (and default_deleter) and static memory (in this case there would be no deleter) - I didn't thought about that earlier and this seems like the best option here.

Comment: @FreddieChopin: Actually, you can't use `default_deleter` (mistake in my comment) because that is built to be a function object, not a function pointer.  But writing the deleter is easy enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a type-erased deleter, in the same fashion that `shared_ptr` does (but not the way `unique_ptr` does, where it becomes part of the type).

```
class Base
{
public:
    typedef void (*StorageDeleter)(void*);

    Base(void* storage, size_t storageSize, StorageDeleter deleter = nullptr) :
        storage_{storage},
        storageSize_{storageSize},
        deleter_{deleter}
    {
        // do something with the storage...
    }

    virtual ~Base()
    {
        // do something with the storage...
        if (deleter_) deleter_(storage_);
    }

    // member functions

private:
    void* storage_;
    size_t storageSize_;
    StorageDeleter deleter_;
};

/* no changes to this one */
template<size_t Size>
class StaticObject;

class DynamicObject : public Base
{
    static void array_deleter(void* p) { uint8_t* pExact = (uint8_t*)p; delete [] pExact; }
public:
    DynamicObject(size_t size) :
        DynamicObject{std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>{new uint8_t[size]}, size}
    {

    }

private:
    DynamicObject(std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>&& dynamicStorage, size_t size) :
        Base{dynamicStorage.get(), size, &DynamicObject::array_deleter},
    {
        dynamicStorage.release();
    }
};
```

Note that the deleter is a static member function -- it doesn't require a live derived instance of `DynamicObject` to operate correctly.

I also fixed the your usage of `std::unique_ptr` so that the array deallocator gets used in case of an exception thrown during construction of `Base` (after construction, the deleter function is responsible).

Now, consider that (pointer+deleter) already exists, in the form of `std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter>`.  So you can do:

```
class Base
{
    typedef void (*StorageDeleter)(void*);
    typedef std::unique_ptr<void, StorageDeleter> AutofreePtr;

public:
    Base(AutofreePtr&& storage, size_t storageSize) :
        storage_{std::move(storage)},
        storageSize_{storageSize}
    {
        // do something with the storage...
    }

    virtual ~Base()
    {
        // do something with the storage...
    }

    // member functions

private:
    AutofreePtr storage_;
    size_t storageSize_;
};

template<size_t Size>
class StaticObject : public Base
{
    static void no_delete(void*) {}
public:

    StaticObject() :
        Base{{&storage, &StaticObject::no_delete}, Size}
    {

    }

private:

    typename std::aligned_storage<Size>::type staticStorage_;
};

class DynamicObject : public Base
{
    static void array_deleter(void* p) { uint8_t* pExact = (uint8_t*)p; delete [] pExact; }
public:

    DynamicObject(size_t size) :
        DynamicObject{{new uint8_t[size], &DynamicObject::array_deleter}, size}
    {

    }
};
```

Comment: IMO, if one wanted to go this route, one should seriously consider just using `std::shared_ptr`; the added simplicity and flexibility is likely to outweigh the slight overhead it would impose.

Comment: @Hurkyl: But even if you use a null deleter, `shared_ptr` will still dynamically allocate the metadata object, violating the requirements.  I did consider it, and figured it was ok to pay the "reference-counting" cost, but not add dynamic allocation when the question specifically precludes it.

Comment: @Hurkyl: On the other hand, one should be able to use `std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[], void (*)(void*)>` and pass either a no-op deleter or `default_deleter`, and not pay any more overhead.

Comment: @BenVoigt - your last comment (with your answer) seems like a very good idea - I could put such std::unique_ptr in Base and std::move() it from constructors of derived classes. This seems like a perfect solution and would probably be the shortest too!

Comment: @FreddieChopin: Ok, I think this is what that would look like.

Answer (score 1):

This avoids the problem of using a storage object for work before it may have been fully initialized.

```
class Base
{
public:

    Base(void* storage, size_t storageSize) :
        storage_{storage},
        storageSize_{storageSize}
    {
    }

    virtual ~Base()
    {
    }

private:
    void* storage_;
    size_t storageSize_;
};

class Worker
{
    Worker(Base* storage)
        : storage(storage)
    {
        // do something with the storage
    }

    ~Worker()
    {
        // do something with the storage
    }

    Base* storage;
};

Base* storage = new FancyStorage;
Worker w(storage);
delete storage;
```

I avoided smart pointers to keep it simple as I don't know how you want your storage objects to be owned.

Comment: There's no inheritance here :(  Polymorphism seems to be a key requirement of the question.

Comment: @BenVoigt Implementation of `FancyStorage` is left as an exercise.. see the last lines of code.

Comment: @BenVoigt - I don't require polymorphism, but I'd like the derived object to be easily usable and the "static" variant must not use any dynamic memory.

Comment: @NeilKirk - I don't see how could I apply your solution to my problem. I would like the objects to be completely "contained" (usable standalone). How would you partition the Base, StaticObject and DynamicObject from the question to use your Base and Worker? Where would each part go?

Comment: @FreddieChopin I don't understand. Instead of incorporating the storage directly into the class which does "something" with it, the storage is abstracted out to another set of classes.

Comment: @NeilKirk - my ideal solution - I can instantiate a DynamicObject or StaticObject, use all member functions of Base on it, convert it to reference of Base and _NOT_ have to provide wrappers and conversion operators in these "final" classes. Either I don't understand how to apply your solution to my problem, or it would be identical to what I have now ("holder" classes with wrappers and conversion operators).

Comment: @FreddieChopin I don't understand what you are doing, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you really want is to reverse the hierarchy; a `Base` should have some storage, rather than, say, a `StaticObject` having a `Base`. This can, for example, be implemented with generics

```
template< typename Storage >
class Base
{
    Storage storage; // Storage could be a private base class too
public:
    // Fix: use perfect forwarding
    template< typename T... >
    Base(T ...args):Storage(args...) { /* More initialization */ }

    ~Base() {
        // Still safe to use storage!
    }

    void set_all_storate_to_zero()
    {
        memset(storage.ptr(), 0, storage.size());
    }
};
```

Comment: What's the polymorphic pointer type?  You can't use `Base*` with this solution, you need `Base<Storage>*` which disallows mixing storage schemes.

Comment: I have thought about that too, but this will duplicate the compiled code - Base<StaticStorage> and Base<DynamicStorage> would be two distinct classes (so actually they would NOT be common) with their distinct set of (identical) functions.

Comment: @Ben: `Base` in the OP is already not suitable for dynamic polymorphism. If the OP so desired, he could make `Storage` a polymorphic type.

Comment: @Hurkyl: But, `Base<Storage>` doesn't use `Storage` in a polymorphic way.